# Multiple Subscriptions

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I'm currently trying to implement Stripe in my app, but it looks like the Stripe Cloud module of Parse is missing an important part.

From the Stripe docs:

> Stripe offers the ability to subscribe a single customer object to multiple subscriptions. Each subscription will have a unique ID and its state is handled independently from other subscriptions.

And to do that, you should use stripe.customers.createSubscription

But there is no createSubscription method in Stripe.Customers on parse.
https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Stripe.Customers.html

I just don't understand how to achieve that.

Actually, you can't even subscribe to a plan without creating a new customer.

Thanks for any help you can provide.
And please excuse me for my english, this is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Never looked at the stripe stuff before.  Maybe you do a regular create to create a customer followed by updateSubscription to make that customer into a recurring one?

Comment: updateSubscription on a user will just change the plan of the first subscription. Using this method will allow only one subscription per customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was having exactly the same issue.
The answer was to do it with an httpRequest.

```
var stripeKey = "sk_test_your_secret_key"
Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeCustomerToPlan", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:"POST",
        url: "https://" + stripeKey + ":@api.stripe.com/v1/customers/" + request.params.customerId + "/subscriptions",
        body:{
            "plan": request.params.plan
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success(httpResponse);
        },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I did. Thanks for putting it into words ;)